# Converting Html string to Attributed string and assigning to textview getting extra space

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textview

I spent more than 8 hours, but could not able to fix my issue. 
My code as below:

```
let sampleHTML = "<p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" style=\"\" size=\"1\"><b style=\"\">1. GPS must be turned on<\/b>&nbsp;to locate panel GP clinics within 1 km from your location.<\/font><\/span><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">2.&nbsp;You can do a wildcard search based on “Clinic Name” or “Road Name”.<\/font><\/span><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">3. The top right corner&nbsp;shows the tip of a highlighter which is a <b>Filter<\/b>&nbsp;to find another Panel type eg. TCM or Specialist Panel (where applicable).<\/font><\/span><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">4. When the search is done, click on your desired panel clinic and you can<\/font><\/span><\/p><blockquote style=\"margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;\"><p class=\"p2\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><b><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">(a) View Clinic Operating hours<\/font><\/b><\/span><\/p><\/blockquote><blockquote style=\"margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;\"><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><b style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">(b) Call the clinic<\/font><\/b><\/p><\/blockquote><blockquote style=\"margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;\"><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><b style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">(c) Get Direction to the panel clinic (GPS must be turned on)<\/font><\/b><\/p><\/blockquote><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">5.If <b>GPS is not turned on<\/b>, you can still access to 4a and 4b for your selected panel clinic.<\/font><\/span><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><b><i style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">Important Notice<\/font><\/i><\/b><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">(1) <i>*Last Clinic Registration is<\/i>&nbsp;<b>30 Minutes before closing time or earlier<\/b> if the number of patients’ registration exceeded the capacity that the attending doctor and clinic staff can handle that goes beyond the clinic normal operating hours.<\/font><\/span><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">(2) <b>Surcharge<\/b> will be imposed on members for visit <i>on or after *Last Clinic Registration<\/i>.<\/font><\/span><\/p><p class=\"p1\" style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Menlo;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><font color=\"#000000\" size=\"1\">(3) <b>Operating hours<\/b> are indicative. Please call the clinic before visiting as clinics’ operating hours may change without prior notice.<\/font><\/span><\/p><div><font color=\"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.850980392156863)\" face=\"Menlo\" size=\"1\"><br><\/font><\/div><div><font size=\"1\"><img src=\"data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABAAAAAQACAIAAADwf7zUAAAKMWlDQ1BJQ0MgUHIAQAAAAAICAEAAAAACAgBAAAAAAgIAQAAAAAICD\/H8\/yGKggh8zsAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\"><\/font><font color=\"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.850980392156863)\" face=\"Menlo\"><span style=\"font-size: 1px;\"><br><\/span><\/font><\/div>"
```

Converting html to attributed string extension as below:

```
    extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)

            //[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }

    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }   
}
```

Loading attributed text to textview as below:

```
cell.txtViewHTML.attributedText = sampleHTML.htmlToAttributedString
```

The output screenshot as below:

[image: Getting extra spacing in between, if i load same in webview it is looking fine]

I believe something wrong in my code, can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which extra space? Between Important notice and point a?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma  point 4 - a & important notice - a.

Comment: That is in your HTML.. extra <p></p> Remove that.. or play around with that..

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma, i think the problem with html not with my code.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma, when i have image in html string, textview it is not displaying image completely. I have edited my question, not able to add image src path to html content due to limit in number of characters. please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some modifications in your HTML code:

```
let sampleHTML = "<p><b>1. GPS must be turned on</b>&#160;to locate panel GP clinics within 1 km from your location.</p><p><b>2.</b>&#160;You can do a wildcard search based on &#8220;Clinic Name&#8221; or &#8220;Road Name&#8221;.</p><p><b>3. The top right corner</b>&#160;shows the tip of a highlighter which is a&#160;<b>Filter</b>&#160;to find another Panel type eg. TCM or Specialist Panel (where applicable).</p><p>4. When the search is done, click on your desired panel clinic and you can<ol type=\"a\"><li><b>View Clinic Operating hours</b></li><li><b>Call the clinic</b></li><li><b>Get Direction to the panel clinic (GPS must be turned on).</b></li></ol></p><p><b>5.</b>&#160;If&#160;<b>GPS is not turned on</b>, you can still access to S/no 4a and 4b for your selected panel clinic.</p><h1><p><i><font size=\"3\">Important Notice</font></i></h1><ol type=\"a\"><li><i>*Last Clinic Registration is&#160;</i><b>30 Minutes before closing time or earlier</b>if the number of patients&#8217; registration exceeded the capacity that the attending doctor and clinic staff can handle that goes beyond the clinic normal operating hours.</li><li><b>Surcharge&#160;</b>will be imposed on members for visit&#160;<i>on or after *Last Clinic Registration.</i></li><li><b>Operating hours&#160;</b>are indicative. Please call the clinic before visiting as clinics&#8217; operating hours may change without prior notice.</li></ol></p>"
```

.

**Sample Output from StackOverflow "Blockquotes"**

> **1. GPS must be turned on** to locate
>   panel GP clinics within 1 km from your
>   location.
>
> **2.** You can do a wildcard search based on
>   “Clinic Name” or “Road Name”.
>
> **3. The
>   top right corner** shows the tip of a highlighter which is
>   a **Filter** to find another Panel type eg. TCM or
>   Specialist Panel (where applicable).
>
> 4. When the search is done,
>   click on your desired panel clinic and you can
>
> **View Clinic Operating hours**
>
> **Call the
>   clinic**
>
> **Get Direction to the panel clinic (GPS must be
>   turned on).**
>
> **5.** If **GPS is not
>   turned on**, you can still access to S/no 4a and 4b for your
>   selected panel clinic.
>
> ## *Important
>   Notice*
>
> **Last Clinic Registration
>   is* **30 Minutes before closing time or earlier**if the
>   number of patients’ registration exceeded the capacity that the
>   attending doctor and clinic staff can handle that goes beyond the
>   clinic normal operating hours.
>
> **Surcharge** will be
>   imposed on members for visit *on or after *Last Clinic
>   Registration.*
>
> **Operating hours** are indicative.
>   Please call the clinic before visiting as clinics’ operating
>   hours may change without prior notice.

**Sample output in Simulator: (Please ignore the screenshot background)**
[image]

Let me know if you need any help on the HTML part.

Comment: what modifications have you made ?

Comment: You can check the updated HTML added in answer. And just a quick thing: 1. I have removed the extra <p></p> tags. 2. Closing position on </p> tags changes a bit.

Comment: but in webview it looks fine.

Comment: I am not sure why it is correct in WebView. But in TextView extra space comes with <p></p> tag. I got this issue last year.

Comment: thanks, i can show this as reference to my Project manager, that problem with html.

Comment: when i have image in html string, textview it is not displaying image completely. I am edited my question, please look into it.